# How to delete parallel ports on Windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, printer

Im trying to delete the extra parallel ports that come with Windows XP SP3. I've tried deleting the ports through the method recommended by Microsoft ie through Printer & Faxes/File/Server Properties/Ports/ Delete Port. Doesnt work; gives the following message:
Operation Not Supported. I escpecially want to delete a virtual LPT port that is created on installing a certain receipt printer from Epson, the redirect that printer to the native LPT1 port. Can this be done

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find them here: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262032)

Make a backup first!

I can't test it, but this is similar to other ports I have had to clear. So take this as a good suggestion more than a final answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Device Manager.
Shortcut to get there:

Start->Run  devmgmt.msc

You will find a category for ports and then open that up and you should see COM and LPT1 ports.